# Wait for this completion handler to complete execution before the function returns value

Tags: ios, swift

This is the code I have:

```
     func authenticateCredentials(usernameString: String, passwordString: String) -> () -> Bool {
        func isAuthUser() -> Bool {

        client.invokeAPI("AuthenticateAndFetchData",
                         body: nil,
                         httpMethod: "GET",
                         parameters: ["userid": usernameString,"password":passwordString],
                         headers: nil)
        {
            (result, response, error) -> Void in
            if let err = error {
                print("ERROR ", err)

            } else if let res = result {



                    let jsonArray = res as! NSArray
                    for value in jsonArray[0] as! NSDictionary {
                        let jsonstring = value.value as! String
                        NetworkService.jsonResponse = jsonstring
                        if let data = jsonstring.data(using: .utf8) {
                            if let content = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []),
                                let array = content as? [[String: Any]]
                            {
                                for jsondict in array {
                                    let auth = jsondict["IsAuth"]! as! String
                                    self.isAuth = (auth == "true") ? true : false
                                    let substring = NetworkService.parseJSONString(jsonString: jsonstring, key: "Activities")
                                    let substring2 = NetworkService.parseJSONString(jsonString: substring(), key: "activityname")
                                    let activityString = NetworkService.parseJSONvalue(jsonString:substring())
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return self.isAuth
        }
        return isAuthUser

    }

}
```

I call this function on login button. But when I press the button for the first time with correct credentials, this function returns `false`, when I press again, then I completion handler had executed, it changes the `isAuth` to true and the function returns true.

So, I have to press the button twice to make the authentication, How can I make it return true first time only. I want to wait for the execution of completion block before the function returns.

Comment: Instead of returning true or false from your function. call it Async and put your code in completion handler

Comment: Thanks for response. I am new to swift. Can you please help me how do I call the function async.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your client call is already async and calls its completion handler on the main queue, add a completion handler as an extra argument to your method:

```
func authenticateCredentials(usernameString: String, passwordString: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
    client.invokeAPI("AuthenticateAndFetchData",
                 body: nil,
                 httpMethod: "GET",
                 parameters: ["userid": usernameString,"password":passwordString],
                 headers: nil) {
        ...
        let auth = jsondict["IsAuth"]! as! String
        let isAuth = (auth == "true") ? true : false
        ...
        completion(isAuth)
    }
}
```

You can than call it like this:

```
authenticateCredentials(usernameString: "user", passwordString: "pass") { (isAuth:Bool) in
    self.isAuth = isAuth
    // go on with whatever you want to do and use self.isAuth successfully
}
```

Comment: completion takes bool as a b parameter or void?

Comment: xcode asks me to add @escaping in front of completion parameter

Comment: I did not get the calling part,  when i call the function, isAuth: Bool in self.isAuth = isAuth. It is giving compiler error.

Comment: `            nw.authenticateCredentials(usernameString: userid!, passwordString: password!){
                isAuth:Bool in
                nw.isAuth = isAuth
            }`

Comment: My mistake, sorry. Updated answer.

Comment: idk why but its still behaving the same way. I have to click two times to get true. First time pressing button simply passes the completion and sends false. When I click again, the completion handler runs and sends true.

Comment: Then `client.invokeAPI` calls its completion block before it is authenticated.

Comment: Then what should I do now? Is there any solution?

Comment: should i use GCD here? Is yes, how can i do that?

Comment: Fix `invokeAPI` or the backend, if it sends the wrong value (isAuth == false).

Comment: In case `invokeAPI` is not already running in the background you should use GDC. But this is not the root of your issue. How to is another question. First try to find the answer yourself and, if you have issues, post a new question showing what you have tried.

Comment: invokeAPI is the azure API to invoke the REST-API and fetch data from server. I can't do much about it.